# Socket error - with simple socket programming using python

Tags: python, sockets

There is a server process listening in my machine at port 8000. And, a client process is trying to communicate to the server continuously. Everytime it opens a new socket connection and closes the connection for some reason. This is a continuously process. But, when I'm trying to do with the pasted code here, I'm unable to create the socket connection after certain limit. In my windows machine, it throws error after creating/closing 16k connections.

Getting an 10055 error while running the example code given here. "Connect failed. Error Code : 10055 Message An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"

```
import socket              
import sys
from time import sleep


HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 8000               
open = 0
close = 0

def connect(host, port, message=None):
    global open
    global close
    open += 1

    s = socket.socket()
#     s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print 'Socket created'
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
    except socket.error , msg:
        print "open count=%s" % open
        print "close count=%s" % close
        print 'Connect failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()
    print "Sending a msg"

    s.sendall('Hello\n') #send only takes string

    count = 1
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print "RECE data:<%s>" % data
        if not data and count < 5:
            print "Wait for data..." 
            count += 1
        else:
            break

    s.shutdown(1)
    s.close()
    del s
    close += 1
    print 'Socket connect complete for %s:%s' % (host, port)

while 1:
    print 'Connected with ',  HOST
    connect(HOST, 8000)
    print "Wait for 1 sec"
    sleep(1)

output like this:
>>>
:
:
Wait for 1 sec
Connected with  <server-ip>
Socket created
Sending a msg
RECE data:<Got your msg: <Hello>
>
Socket connect complete for <server-ip:port>

Wait for 1 sec
Socket created <server-ip>
### open count=16338
### close count=16337
Connect failed. Error Code : 10055 Message An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
<<<
```

Comment: It is possible that your server code is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with windows sockets is that they don't actually die when you close them unless you tell them to. Try adding the following code after you initialise the socket and see what happens.

```
l_onoff = 1
l_linger = 0
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, 
                 struct.pack('ii', l_onoff, l_linger))
```

The documentation for [Lingering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be found at MSDN.

also change your shutdown to:

```
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
```

This should close all connections immediately if windows behaves itself. Which will prevent the buffer error caused by too many sockets lingering.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it didnt work for me. Getting an error like below. I'm using python 2.7 """     s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_DONTLINGER, 0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SO_DONTLINGER'

Comment: @Kalai Got my python back now, here's some working code. Forgot python doesn't support `SO_DONTLINGER`.